# Handle local notification in background and suspended

Tags: ios

I want to perform some task  when local notification fired(assume application is in background/suspended but not in foreground) without taping user on notification. How it possible??.
 i am not able to get  delegate in  application:didReceiveLocalNotification:  in case of  application is in background/suspended and Local Notification fired.
Please any one can suggest some solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: did my answer help you in what you were trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

The `didReceiveLocalNotification` method is only called when you application is running in the foreground. If you see a badge and click on the App to start it, then you need to process the local notification using `application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` (or `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`) To get at your local notification in either of these two methods, use `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey` as a key to the options dictionary.

If your app is in suspended state, you won't be able to know that the notification is fired.